# Recover data deleted by diskpart

Tags: disk-partitioning, file-recovery, diskpart

After accidentally deleting all data on my disk using "clean" on diskpart, my HDD is now empty. I've searched and used some recovery data apps, one of them is EaseUS. After scanning hours, it shows up exactly all data I lost but requiring fee to recover.

I want to know that how all the data is still remained and found by the app while the disk show in my computer is empty and is there any reliable and safe ways to recover all data that do not require money?

*p/s: Sorry for bad english, I hope you guys understand and help me with this problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knoppix is a free data recovery system based on Linux but can recover Windows data as well.

https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html

Create a bootable USB.